# I have a "general computer" question but I'm not sure which Stack Exchange site is appropriate

Tags: support, specific-question, site-recommendation

Basically I have a computer troubleshooting question.

I could wander over to TomsHardware but hey... I like you guys.

Stack Overflow doesn't seem quite right. Server Fault could work, but I'm not sure.

SuperUser could fit, too, but it's hard to say.

Where should I ask it?

Comment: You should give some more information what kind of troubleshooting question it is.  Is it hardware, software, etc?

Comment: What is your question?  Post it here, and we'll tell you where it'd fit. :-)

Comment: Superuser *unless* it's a programming probem (can be solved by code) or if the problem is occurring in a production server environment.

Comment: Super User would be my first guess. Check their [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Sounds like you should ask Super User (most "general" problems fit there) and it'll be migrated otherwise.

Comment: Ooo, an unanswered question! Oh, no; three people just answered it in comments instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) is the site you want.

From the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking